# Python cannot load shared library

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries

I have recently installed Ubuntu and I am trying to load shared library by python. But everytime I get message:

```
import ctypes
...
fc = ctypes.cdll.libmal

OSError: libmal: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have copied libmal.so to /usr/local/lib and when I print os.environ just before the failing line I get:

```
...'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/usr/local/lib'...
```

Do you have pls some suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: /usr/local/ **lib** vs /usr/local/ **bin**? shared object files need to go to */lib

Comment: [Reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) and you will see that on Linux, it is required to specify the filename and the extension.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you :)